# Can't launch Steam games using optirun (Bumblebee)

Tags: debian, steam, bumblebee

I am using a Lenovo IdeaPad Y580 laptop with an Intel i7 CPU, an Intel HD4000 integrated GPU, and NVIDIA GeForce GTX660M discrete GPU.

I have recently installed Debian testing (jessie) on it, previously using Ubuntu 14.10.

To be able to use the discrete graphics card, I have installed Bumblebee, following the [guide](http://wiki.debian.org/Bumblebee) on Debian wiki. All apps seemed to run right using optirun.

Then, I installed Steam from the repository. Problem is, that optirun fails to launch any game ran from Steam (you can notice that the user status changes to In-Game for a while, but then reverts to online). Running games using the integrated GPU works perfectly fine.

I believe that there is some problem with the libraries. I noticed, that when editing the Bumblebee config from:

`PrimusLibraryPath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus`

to:

`PrimusLibraryPath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`

Steam appears to launch the game using optirun. However, it is launched by the IGP, guiding by the low FPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is caused by the faulty `libdrm-intel` package, version `2.4.58-2` to be exact. Downgrading to `2.4.56-1` (and installing the dependencies, unfortunately) fixes the problem.

The packages can be downloaded from [here](http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20140810T163814Z/pool/main/libd/libdrm/) (this is from the official debian server, no need to worry). Don't forget to download both i386 and amd64 packages if you are using multiarch.